# Header in latex both running into right margin and offset in left margin

Tags: format, latex

I am currently writing my thesis and I want the current chapter appears on the top of every even page, on the left side.

However one of my chapter headings is rather long and it runs in 2 lines, which looks terrible, so i started working with fancyhdr.

Now the problem is, that simply changing "fancyheadoffset" is not enough so I need to make "headwidth" wider as well. However I don't manage to make thos two things work together...

Here is my what I tried in a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf[lef,rof]{\thepage}%
}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{23pt}
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{1.7\textwidth}
%\fancyheadoffset[LO]{0.1\textwidth}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\section{The multivariate stochastic volatility model of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck type}
\end{document}
```

So the question is: How can I manipulate both headwidth and the offset,

Thanks

Paul